# make multiple asynchronous request in python gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
    import threading
import urllib2

import time
import webapp2

import main

start = time.time()
url = "http://exmple.com?phone="
class BatchSuscriber(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = main.JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('batch.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
        address = self.request.get('address')
        numbers = str(self.request.get('numbers')).split(',')
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=self.fetch_url, args=(phone,)) for phone in numbers]
        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
        self.response.write("Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start))
        self.response.write("<br>")


    def fetch_url(self,phone):
        urlHandler = urllib2.urlopen(url+phone)
        html = urlHandler.read()
        self.response.write(html)
        self.response.write("<br>")
        self.response.write("'%s\' fetched in %ss" % (url+phone, (time.time() - start)))
        self.response.write("<br>")
```

trying to use the above code to make urlfetch asynchronously. From my log, it seems the call is actually serially instead of being parallel. What ways can i achieve this in gae. Thanks.

Comment: does this actually work in production?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to use threads is entirely the wrong approach here. GAE already includes an [asynchronous requests service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests) in `google.appengine.api.urlfetch`; you should use that.